# javascript style background color flashes when set. ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, styles, background-color

I am trying to use javascript to set the background color of a label when a link button is clicked.
However, the background will flash the desired color and then fall back to no background.  Below I have the javascript function as well as the control in question.
I've tried forcing a redraw with a display='none',display='' but no avail.
Also, I've tried making the label not run at server by making it a standard control.
I've also put breaks on both areas the style is set, and the LightGreen is called, but the blank is not, so not sure where the background is being blanked out as this is not being specified anywhere else.
Thanks, James

**The Label**

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Font-Bold="true" id="lblCustomer">Customer:</asp:Label>
```

**The Javascript**

```
function CheckUncheckAll(clientID, listID, check) {
        var chk = clientID.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (var i = 0; i < chk.length; i++) {
            chk[i].checked = check;
        }
        if (check) {
            document.getElementById(listID.id).style.backgroundColor = "LightGreen";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(listID.id).style.backgroundColor = "";
        }
    }
```

**The Code Behind**

```
lbCustomerAll.Attributes.Add("onclick", "CheckUncheckAll(" + ckbxlstCustomer.ClientID + ", " + lblCustomer.ClientID + ", true)");
```

Comment: sounds like you're not preventing the default action for the link from firing, which is probably why you're seeing the change flash on the screen and then disappear.

Comment: If you already have `listId`, there is no need to do `document.getElementById(listId.id)` which will just return the exact same object. Sorry, don't know what is causing your resetting colour issue though

Comment: Could you include the actual HTML that is generated for your label and also your 'link button'... that way it would be easier to confirm what David Hoerster states (which sounds quite likely).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you do something like:

```
function CheckUncheckAll(clientID, listID, check) {
        var evt = document.getElementById(clientID);
        evt.preventDefault();

        var chk = clientID.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (var i = 0; i < chk.length; i++) {
            chk[i].checked = check;
        }
        if (check) {
            document.getElementById(listID.id).style.backgroundColor = "LightGreen";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(listID.id).style.backgroundColor = "";
        }
    }
```

This will prevent the default behavior of the link button from firing.

Comment: This led me to the answer.  I ended up taking out the LinkButton and putting in a blank Hyperlink and disguising it as an active link. Which then didn't have any sort of default action.  Thanks, James

Answer (score 0):

`checked` is not a true/false value, it's a binary attribute.

```
element.checked = true; //will fail
element.checked ='checked'; //will work
```

If the value of "check" being passed is true/false, your code will not work.

P.S. It's worth learning jQuery. You can do all this in one line of code.

Comment: I'm confused, why has `element.checked=true;` worked for me for years, and that the [w3 specification for checkbox controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-checked) calls it a "boolean attribute"?

Comment: @freefaller - you are correct, Diodeus has got confused between the `checked attribute` and the `checked property`... the JavaScript property is boolean, the attribute is string-based and should be set to "checked". `element.checked = true` or `<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />`

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem. By accident, I realized that the issue is with the association of the Button tag and the onclick function.

If I change the button to anything else, like an `h1`, or if I change the function to `onmouseover`, it works. Can`t figure out why, though.